# Two variables in Django URL

Tags: python, regex, django

I want a URL something like this:

```
/(category)/(post-slug)
```

On the link this is what I have:

```
{% url blog.category blog.slug %}
```

and for the url.py:

```
url(r'^(I DON"T KNOW WHAT TO PUT ON THIS PART TO GET THE CATEGORY)/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)', views.post, name='post'),
```

thanks

EDIT:
This is what I have now:
Still have NoReverseMatch error at /

urls.py

```
 url(r'^(?P<category>[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)$', views.post, name='post'),
```

index.html

```
<a href="{% url blog.category blog.slug %}">
```

views.py

```
def post(request, slug, category):
    try:
        blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Blog.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('This post does not exist')
    return render(request, 'parts/post.html', {
        'blog': blog,
    })
```

Comment: If the URL is `/(category)/(post-slug)`, then `{% url category.blog category.slug %}` looks wrong. Shouldn't it be something like `{% url post.category.slug post.slug %}`?

Comment: sorry, I just typed it incorrectly, yes I am using blog.category and blog.slug, my focus is on the regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your URL tag needs the name of the pattern you are reversing as the first argument:

```
{% url 'post' blog.category blog.slug %}
```

or if you are using a namespace, something like:

```
{% url 'blog:post' blog.category blog.slug %}
```

You haven't shown your views or models, so we can only guess what your URL pattern should be. I'm not sure why you find the category confusing - you just need to choose a name for the group (e.g. `category_slug`), and the regex for the group (you might be able to use the same one as you use for `slug`). That would give you:

```
url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)$'
```

Note that there should be a dollar on the end of the regex.

Comment: I am confused with the regex.. I always have NoReverseMatch at / even though I already have that regex of yours?

Comment: This is what I have now

urls.py
 url(r'^(?P<category>[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z._%+-]+)$', views.post, name='post'),

index.html
<a href="{% url blog.category blog.slug %}">

and views.py
def post(request, slug, category):
 try:
  blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
 except Blog.DoesNotExist:
  raise Http404('This post does not exist')
 return render(request, 'parts/post.html', {
  'blog': blog,
 })

Comment: Don't put code in your comments, it's impossible to read. Edit your original question, and include the full traceback. If the error is on your `/` URL, then show the view and template for it as well.

Comment: You still haven't shown the *full* error, or the index view.

Comment: I only get the error when I added the regex on urls.py and the link on index.html

Comment: Yes, since the error is occurring on the index page, you need to show the index view. The full error message might explain *why* you are getting `NoReverseMatch`.

Comment: I've found the error, it is the name of the pattern should be the first argument? And I will read more about it. Thanks!

Comment: I have something like this now in the URL /Django/post how could I make it  all lowercase?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166827/discussion-between-rat-kabu-and-alasdair).

Comment: Your category model should have a slug field and you should use that in the URL. If you only use the category for display in the URL, then you might be able to use the lowercase filter: `{% url blog.category|lower blog.slug %}`. If you're still stuck, please ask a new question because it's a separate issue to your original question.