# Is there anyway to pass more than 2 arguments in Django's template url function?

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to pass 3 arguments to this path:

```
path('assignment/<str:class_id>/<str:assignment_id>/<str:edit>', views.assignment, name='teacher-assignment')
```

Here is the template code:

```
<a href="{% url 'teacher-assignment' class_id=class_id assignment_id=assignment.id|uuid_to_str edit='edit=false' %}">{{ assignment.assignment_name }}</a>
```

However, Django throws a no reverse match found error showing only 2 of these arguments listed in the passed arguments. The template url function's comments also show only 2 arguments being passed. How would I pass 3 arguments to the URL dispatcher?

EDIT:
Here is the full reverse error:
NoReverseMatch at /teacher/assignment/22b95fce8983488db5ca34be80849973/74dba6277a3142d09b1bed77b10bf66f/edit=false
Reverse for 'teacher-assignment' with keyword arguments '{'assignment_id': '74dba6277a3142d09b1bed77b10bf66f', 'edit': 'edit=true'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['teacher/assignment/(?P[^/]+)/(?P[^/]+)/(?P[^/]+)$']

Comment: Can you share the full reverse error? I'm pretty sure you can't have `=` in a valid url

Comment: may it help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49278793/8656493

Comment: Here is the full reverse error:

NoReverseMatch at /teacher/assignment/22b95fce8983488db5ca34be80849973/74dba6277a3142d09b1bed77b10bf66f/edit=false
Reverse for 'teacher-assignment' with keyword arguments '{'assignment_id': '74dba6277a3142d09b1bed77b10bf66f', 'edit': 'edit=true'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['teacher/assignment/(?P<class_id>[^/]+)/(?P<assignment_id>[^/]+)/(?P<edit>[^/]+)$']

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Turns out the reverse error was coming from the HTML file that the reverse was linked to, since when I added a parameter to the url, I didn't check to update the {% url %} statement in the actual html file itself.